# Negative rating questions with positive rating answers

Tags: discussion

I found it bizarre that negative score question can be answered by a positive answer.

Today, someone asked an [identify-this-game question about go-fish](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/59772/how-this-game-called-where-players-collect-sets-of-4) (or Happy Families in the UK), while this is a bit odd question it looks o.k by me.

What I don't get is how come the rating for the question was -2 while the rating for the answer was +3?  And in particular, the person that writes a long, detailed answer, isn't it right for you to make a thumb up for the question?  I mean, you "wasted" some part of your time on this question so it least in your mind it was worth the effort?

I understand that I might be in a minority opinion here, but would love to hear why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, trying to understand or dictate how people cast their votes is an exercise in futility. People can and do vote based on anything, from rational evaluations of post usefulness to grumpiness from missing breakfast. [Or a mod lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/134175).

The particular case of a negatively-voted question with a positively voted answer is not exactly unheard of. A bad question can have a good answer. And people can feel compelled to answer a question without feeling that it is good. Or they may just forget to vote on the question; I myself don't remember to vote on every question I answer.

Answer (score 1):

I answered that question...

As a general rule I do upvote any question that I answer.  I usually answer first, then vote.   That one seems to have slipped through the net, I must have been distracted.

But I agree with the other answer.  Don't seek logic in voting patterns.